# If $f(0)=0,f(1)=1$,find all $a$ such that $\exists \xi\in (0,1)$ such that $f(\xi)+a=f'(\xi)$

Tags: functions, continuity

Let V be the set of all contimuous functions $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R} $, differentiable on $(0,1)$,with the property that $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1)= 1$. Determine all $a\in \mathbb{R}$ such that for every $f\in V$,there exists some $\xi\in (0,1)$ such that
$$f(\xi)+a=f'(\xi)$$
I have tried some functions like $x$ and $x^2$,and find that $a$ must be in $(0,1)$,but I'm not sure if this is the answer.
I also try to construct the function $g(x)=e^{-x}f(x)$,and then $e^{\xi}g'(\xi)=a$.But I don't know how to keep going.
Could someone give me some hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is problem 7 from last year's IMC (2023), as can be found [here](https://www.imc-math.org.uk/?year=2023&section=problems&item=day2).
I know, because I composed this problem :]

For these kinds of problems, you often want to use Rolle's Theorem, which states that if $a < b$ and $f$ is continuous on the interval $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$, satisfying $f(a) = f(b)$, then there exists some $\xi \in (a,b)$ such that $f'(\xi) = 0$. By varying the function $f$ that you apply this to, you can prove statements that one does not immediately recognise as being a corollary of Rolle's theorem. Let me give you an example.

**Problem:** Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable such that $f(0) = f(1) = 0$. Prove that for some $\xi \in (0,1)$ it holds that $f'(\xi) = f(\xi)$.

**Solution:** It is not clear that this is a result of Rolle's theorem, since both $f$ and $f'$ appear in the statement of the problem, but it really is, albeit with some trickery. Namely, let $g(x) = e^{-x}f(x)$. Then also $g(0) = g(1) = 0$, so we may apply Rolle's theorem to $g$ on $(0,1)$. Now, since $$g'(x) = -e^{-x}f(x) + e^{-x}f'(x),$$ we find some $\xi \in (0,1)$ such that $e^{-\xi}f'(\xi) = e^{-\xi}f(\xi)$. Since $e^{-\xi} \neq 0$, we conclude that $f'(\xi) = f(\xi)$, precisely what we wanted to show!

My idea for this problem was rather similar to the example above, but it's a little bit more involved. As the other posted solution already reveals, the only value that will work is $\alpha = 1/(e-1)$ and finding this out was one thing I particularly liked about this problem, as it sets it apart from others of its kind. However, proving that this indeed works will require a refined version of the argument I gave above. Let me know if this helps you at all, I would be happy to give more hints if necessary!

Comment: I find that the problem can be transformed into the example metioned in your answer by solving a differential equation $f(x)+a=f'(x)$. It's really a wonderful problem. Thank you for your help very much!

Answer (score 1):

We want to reduce set of different possibilities for $a$, so it makes sense to try to find a function s.t. $f'(x) - f(x)$ has low number of possible values. If it has just one, then $f'(x) - f(x) = a$, which has solution $f_0(x) = c e^x + d$. Substituting $f(0) = 0$, $f(1) = 1$, we get $f_0(x) = \frac{e^x}{e - 1} - \frac{1}{e - 1}$. This gives $a = \frac{1}{e - 1}$.

Now, the question is if for any $f$ satisfying given conditions, $f(\xi) + a = f'(\xi)$ has solution for $\xi \in (0, 1)$.

Let's write $f(x) = g(x) + f_0(x)$, then $g(0) = g(1) = 0$ and if $f(\xi) + a = f'(\xi)$ is equivalent to $g(\xi) = g'(\xi)$.

If $g$ is zero on $(0, 1)$, then for $\xi$ in this interval $g(\xi) = 0 = g'(\xi)$.

Otherwise, take some interval $(a, b)$ s.t. $g(a) = g(b) = 0$ but $g(x) \neq 0$ for $x \in (a, b)$. Wlog assume $g(x) > 0$ for $x \in (a, b)$.

$g(\xi) = g'(\xi)$ for positive $g$ is equivalent to $(\ln g(\xi))' = 1$. And as $\ln g(a + \epsilon)$ is very large negative number, $\ln g(\frac{a + b}{2})$ is finite, $(\ln g(x))'$ is positive and very large for some $x \in (a, \frac{a + b}{2})$. Similarly, $(\ln g(x))'$ is negatibe and very large for some $x \in (\frac{a+b}2, b)$. Thus, by intermediate value theorem, $(\ln g(x))' = 1$ for some $x \in (a, b)$.